# Open ID connect MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect

There are lots of material available on internet regarding OPEN ID CONNECT. Unfortunately, all those material belongs to ASP.NET Core.

I want to implement OPEN ID connect on MVC 5.

Below is the code for Asp.net Core which is working fine (I TRIED).

```
     public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            // identity server confoguration
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
             .AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect(options => SetOpenIdConnectOptions(options));



            //end identity server
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            // identity server
            app.UseAuthentication();
            // indetity server
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }


        // identity server configuration
        private void SetOpenIdConnectOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
           options.Authority = "XXX";

            options.ClientId = "XXX";

            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("default-api");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        }
    }
```

So i want above code to work on MVC 5. i tried to write the above code in MVC 5 but didn't worked. Seems like i am missing something because i am unable to get Token-ID or user Claims

Below is the code for MVC 5 (I TRIED but DIDNT WORKED).

**I am unable to get token-id as well as user claim.**

---

public partial class Startup
    {

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });



        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


        //app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            RedirectUri = "XXX",
            Authority = "XXX",
            ClientId = "XXX",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            SaveTokens = true,
            Scope = "openid profile default-api offline_access",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
        });


    }

}
```

---

Thank in Adnvance :)

Comment: "didn't work" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "didn't work" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that "didn't work" when you tried to drive it, without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your post. Thanks.